# differences between Gale-Shapley stable solutions

Tags: algorithms, game-theory

I'm looking for the properties of the man-optimal and women-optimal stable solutions of the Gale-Shapley algorithm. I found dozens of references proving that depending on which side proposes, one gets different stable solutions, but I have yet to find anything which answers questions like: How different are these two solutions? Are there preference lists where the differences are larger or smaller? On what does this depend? If all men have identical preference lists and all women have identical preference lists, does this lead to a smaller difference between the two optimal matchings?  Can someone point me to anything in this direction?